# how to convert _InternalLinkedHashMap to list object in dart

Tags: dart

I have recieved some data from server side, and it parsed as `LinkedHashMap` by default, now I want to convert `LinkedHashMap` to `List<Oject>`, this is the code I am using now:

```
var articles = result["list"];
      List<String> genreIdsList = new List<String>.from(articles);
      var items = genreIdsList.map((String str)=>Item.fromJson(str)).toList();
```

but it did not work as expect. Shows this error:

```
/flutter (10074): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (10074): #0      new List.from (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:40:5)
E/flutter (10074): #1      Repo._getArticles (package:cruise/src/common/repo.dart:82:39)
E/flutter (10074): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10074): #2      Repo.getArticles (package:cruise/src/common/repo.dart:27:12)
E/flutter (10074): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (10074): #3      initArticles (package:cruise/src/page/home/components/homelistdefault_component/effect.dart:42:25)
E/flutter (10074): <asynchronous suspension>
```

This is the result data:

[image]

and this is my fromJson:

```
  factory Item.fromJson(String str) => Item.fromMap(json.decode(str));
```

what should I do to parse the `LinkedHashMap` to `List<Item>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
  List articles = result["list"];
  List<Item> items = [];
  articles.forEach((element) {
    Item item = Item.fromMap(element as Map<String, dynamic>);
    items.add(item);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Now I parse it like this:

```
List articles = result["list"];
      List<Item> items = List.empty(growable: true);
      articles.forEach((element) {
        HashMap<String,Object> map = HashMap.from(element);
        Item item = Item.fromMap(map);
        items.add(item);
      });
      return items;
```